# How Many 5 Card Hands Have At Least 2 7s

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find out how many 5 card hands have at least two 7s. I came up with the following solution:

$${4 \choose 2}{48 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 3}{48 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 4}{48 \choose 1} = 108336$$

Is this correct or am I on the right track?

Comment: What about thinking about it like all of the 5 card hands, and then subtract all of the hands with less than 2 7's. So we would get ${52 \choose 5}-{48 \choose 5}-4*{48 \choose 4}$ because we have all the 5 card hands, then subtract all hands without any 5's and then subtract all hands with exactly one 5.

Comment: Which is the act same thing. So yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed, there's nothing wrong with that; it just isn't much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is okay.   Count the suits for the sevens, for 2 to 4 sevens, and ways to select the remainder from the non-sevens, gives the count of 5 hand cards with at least 2 sevens. (Assuming a standard deck and no joker, as usual.)

$$\binom{4}{2}\dbinom{48}{3}+\binom{4}{3}\dbinom{48}{2}+\binom{4}{4}\dbinom{48}{1}$$

---

Alternatively, you could try complements, but it isn't any simpler in this case: $$\dbinom {52}{5}-\dbinom{48}5-\dbinom{48}4\dbinom{4}1$$